# Why is Google OAuth2 adding a hash to the url?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am having an issue where when my server redirects back to my client web app after successful Google OAuth authentication, a hash gets appended to the url.

For instance, if upon success I redirect back to root "/", I see "http://localhost:8080/#" in the browser URL.

I have narrowed down where this is coming from. On the final response from Google OAuth, there is a hash in the URL, always. Here are the final query params it sends back:

```
ssdc: 1
sidt: ALWU2cvia4QRXzs7Dw3RqBfg8YQloLpX9C5aUg+HM4Xpf+CTHcIafxUfqip/WhuRQqvkS6FTV84grnPqkA8iu/1gXWozhzPrctLG9B0IZ5a9kRfNm6f56tP1kT2u+DqrRgWn8BYWfux11IqrwHMB6PcYRrvRFqssyhyAzH4ADAwAo9hgYI5P0jv5cX25JsKPzlp84sgXDjxeEPyoAp5Z+eOVVbc/utE0rnwsmIk+SZ+fKEag1WovgpQmNUHkImSK5DAWx+tLmTTXssRcYKNqI7I/bLE6v+aBRMG15o16NYHwnEwIWBPMBas=
continue: https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/consent?authuser=0&part=AJi8hAObZlj15NP250sAY5c2G0NxmM46FDwsq9h5-6kQpoUvx4YDP_kq9610R0xh5kNmB6qxh0j54ERZaqnCkgOtiBX2pMqGmbw7hMLtNYQBksHIxMdjqim7rZj53JvsNzLetjoxzgj2cC9lwO1Na1R2yjMDjS6djB7aEX59UFRnT7NBnavIvvlk1OSb5O-IPTT8acugrXzV0nLnsT_kjVaECCu76Zj-bzJDJ8ccwuaJuwQPTbSmpgCRsswg-r566_CRDJ2pk8kT4c5tb0FMxNi7dnGiC1dsPAP2kwWWXWqqK8XuleSxVFjeBEGyMifGJpznOVzbj7GCFU-eZV_wYQAzgnjevVgpZCG-7Q2baH2qV8cIsvLlD-98kH8otyrys43sKCb8i6F7_WxBTWJRls9_RkRRWCHD4NYcWO8qEBdpZ7qYiNrs024&as=ou5INRbruyDfQ9BJQP-a-Q&rapt=AEjHL4PzN394wu-BbPb_rqVCLIv00iA6DcNucHv5DNZvGDs01pCKVQ9wp-i6_s6gwMqd-ylu4NDJjHCS-NzBCIf6DUCMz3Q18A&auth=hwdgWa5prArgTRk23gd04OOn18em2r18KIAtELLsHC3K__GXHILmi5WLvm2dUtFSkAiZGA.#
tcc: 1
```

That final hash in "continue" is being added to the browser URL.

Why is Google doing this? Is this specific to the OAuth spec? I don't think other provides do this.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way around this? It's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

After authorization, add javascript:

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href.replace( /#.*/, ""));
```